# Using gawk to Replace a Pattern of Text with the Contents of a File Whose Filename is Inside the Text

Tags: text, awk, sed, gawk, ed

I am trying to replace text inside a text file according to a certain criteria.

For example, if I have three text files, with outer.txt containing:

```
   Blah Blah Blah
   INCLUDE inner1.txt
   Etcetera Etcetera
   INCLUDE inner2.txt
   end of file
```

And inner1.txt containing:

```
  contents of inner1
```

And inner2.txt containing:

```
  contents of inner2
```

At the end of the replacement, the outer.txt file would look like:

```
    Blah Blah Blah
    contents of inner1
    Etcetera Etcetera
    contents of inner2
    end of file
```

The overall pattern would be that for every instance of the word "INCLUDE", replace that entire line with the contents of the file whose filename immediately follows that instance of "INCLUDE", which in one case would be inner1.txt and in the second case would be inner2.txt.

Put more simply, is it possible for gawk to be able to determine which text file is to be embedded into the outer text file based on the very contents to be replaced in the outer text file?

Comment: Do your lines all start with multiple spaces?

Comment: They all start with varying numbers of spaces and/or tabs. Though it doesn't matter to me if they are replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk --load readfile '{if ($1=="INCLUDE") {printf readfile($2)} else print}' outer.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/( *)INCLUDE(.*)/printf "%s" "\1";cat \2/e' outer.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the +x bit on the edit-file ('chmod +x edit-file'), then you can do:

```
g/include/s//cat/\
.w\
d\
r !%
w
q
```

**Explanation**:

> **`g/include/s//cat/\`**

Starts a global command.

> **`.w\`**

(from within the global context), overwrites the edit-file with the current line only (effectively: 'cat included_file', where you replace included_file for the filename in question.)

> **`d\`**

(from within the global context), deletes the current line from the buffer. (i.e. deletes 'include included_file', again, included_file standing for the file in question).

> **`r !%`**

(from within the global context), reads the output from executing the default file (which is file we are editing, and was overwritten above with 'cat...').

> **`w`**

(finally, outside the global context). Writes (saves) the buffer back to the edit-file.

> **`q`**

quit.

Answer (score 0):

Another `ed` approach would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s outer.txt <<-'EOF'
  /Blah Blah Blah/+1kx
  /end of file/-1ky
  'xr inner.txt
  'xd
  'yr inner2.txt
  'yd
  %p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is required
- Remove the `%p` to silence the output.